# Cisco ASA-5508 FP - Internet Usage Reporting

Tags: internet, usage

We have a new ASA-5508 setup as our main internet GW/FW.

Our boss has asked for an internet usage report. He believes much of the bandwidth may be used for non-business related traffic (streaming, sports, etc.). By "walk around management", he has enough subjective info to make this assertion.

Regarding the Cisco ASA-5508, it doesn't seem to have any built in capability to give a fundamental internet usage report. What options are there for gathering the data and generating a report? Something straightforward like `Top Visited Sites`, or `Top End Point Talkers (by IP, protocol/application)`.

*(I remember ten years ago I had to resort to NTOP and do port mirroring on a switchport where the LAN side of the FW was in order to get some basic reports. I would hope ten years later things have matured and that basic internet usage reporting is more readily available.)*

Can someone advise? I have only recently got back into using an ASA. I put in my first ASA-5501 more than a decade ago. I'm not a CCIE. Just an IT Guy trying to help get my boss what he needs.